# Automatically adjust ylim to include control limits

Tags: r

I have several sets of data, each with differing ranges for display(some examples: 4077 - 5472, 1340 - 1577, 632 - 751, etc) I want to have my plot windows automatically size themselves to accommodate the control limits that I'm plotting along with the means?

```
plot(x = seq(size), means, pch = 20, **ylim=c(?,?)**, ylab="Mean", main="Analysis of Means", xaxt = 'n')
axis(1,seq(size))
segments(seq(size), u, seq(size), means)
lines(seq(1, 15, 1), rep(u_vec + seg, each = 1), type = "S")
lines(seq(1, 15, 1), rep(u_vec - seg, each = 1), type = "S")
abline(h=u)
```

Comment: ylim=c(0,max(mean)+25) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a generic approach, you could add the standard deviation (or another error term) of the original data to the min and max, respectively.

```
data(iris)

with(iris, plot(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width)) # a plot 

# could make limits outside of plot
low.lim <- with(iris, min(Sepal.Length)-sd(Sepal.Length))
upp.lim <- with(iris, max(Sepal.Length)+sd(Sepal.Length))

with(iris, plot(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width, ylim=c(low.lim,upp.lim)))
```